# python if-else recursive function returns undesired value

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, if-statement, return

I'm facing a conditional logic problem here.

I want a value from user, but it should only be confined to either

```
'ABC','DEF' or'XYZ'
```

If not provided with one of the above, program should give the user another chance to enter until it gets the input only from it's expected values

My snippet is as follows:-

```
def foo():
    inp_val=raw_input("Enter value\n>> ")
    if inp_val.upper() not in {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}:
        print("Invalid Input")
        foo()
    return inp_val
inp = foo()
```

Output

```
Enter value
>> 42342d*@r2
Invalid Input
Enter value
>> abc
```

Checking `inp` in python console:-

```
>> inp
ABC #(Expected)
42342d*@r2 #(Actual)
```

Why is this happening?

I tried the reverse logic too:-

```
def bar():
    inp_val=raw_input("Enter value\n>> ")
    if inp_val.upper() in {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}:
        return inp_val
    else:
        print("invalid input")
        bar()
inp = bar()
```

Output:

```
Enter value
>> 42342d*@r2
Invalid Input
Enter value
>> abc
```

In console:

```
>> inp
ABC #Expected
    #(Actual)
```

How do I get the actual value?

Comment: You're not assigning the return from the recursive call, so it's always the *first* input, even if that was invalid.

Comment: Your recursion would be better replaced by an explicit loop.

Comment: @khelwood: Yup, I did just that, in one of the answers below. I wanted to try recursion for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return foo() when recursively calling your function.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

   def foo():
       inp_val=raw_input("Enter value\n>> ")
       if inp_val.upper() not in {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}:
           print("Invalid Input")
           return foo()
       return inp_val
   inp = foo()
   print(inp)
```

Effect:

```
~/sandbox » python a.py                                                                                                                                                                                          tracma01@londev1tracma01
Enter value
>> f
Invalid Input
Enter value
>> ABC
ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    def foo():
            inp_val=input("Enter value\n>> ")
            if inp_val.upper() not in {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}:
                    print("Invalid Input")
                    return foo()
            else:
                    return inp_val

    inp = foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

My own take on this:-

```
   def bar():
        temp = True
        while temp:
            inp_val = raw_input("Enter value\n>> ")
            if inp_val.upper() in {'ABC','DEF','XYZ'}:
                temp = False
                return inp_val
            else:
                print("invalid input")
```

Sure it takes loops and not recursion, and is less efficient. But if want to save memory by not backtracking, try this.

Comment: Your `temp` variable is redundant. Hitting the `return` statement will exit the function. And I'm not sure what you mean by "less efficient".